～もいいところ: いい Can be used sarcastically?
I was reading into some meanings of the common いいところ, and came across this usage:

③《多く否定的な語をあげ「も―」の形で》甚だしい。
「見当違いも―だ」「ご都合主義も━だ」 ▽「いい」は「よい」とも言う。「ところ」は「とこ」とも言う。
I could only find a listing of いい itself meaning something in this fashion in 三省堂:
⑪皮肉な意味で使う。 「━〔＝相当な〕めいわくだ・━年をして〔＝分別のある年ごろなのに〕みっともない・━〔＝おかしな〕かっこうですみません」
〔「よい」の形では言いにくい〕

Jisho gives this example:

彼の母親は可哀相だ。
あいつときたら母親泣なかせもいいところだ。
I feel sorry for his
mom; he really puts her through the wringer.

It seems like when used with も, いいところ can express negativity or sarcasm somehow? It isn't clear if the 三省堂 definition for いい itself is the one applied in いいところ either.
What do both いい and ところ mean in this expression? Is ~もいいところ just a fixed expression?

～もいいところだ is so "fixed" to me that I never felt sarcasm in it. It's indeed hard to break it down, so practically speaking, you may have to memorize it as it is. Some people have tried to analyze it, but none seemed very convincing to me.
Still, if you're still curious, this answer lists two possible interpretations for this construction:

いいところ means "good/lucky one", so 冗談もいいところだ means "Even (calling it) a joke is a good one", which yields something like "Even calling it a joke is an understatement!"

いいところ means "acceptable/possible limit". It's used like this:

この指輪だと、いいところ5000円ですかね。
For this ring, I'd say it's worth 5000 yen at most.

So 冗談もいいところだ means "Even jokes have acceptable limits (and this joke is beyond it)". If you know how 冗談にも程がある works, it's in the same vein. But the main weakness of this theory is that 冗談にもいいところがある never means the same thing.


Again, to be honest, I'm not fully satisfied with either explanation, but I cannot think of a better explanation for this...

When you say memorize “as is” I actually don’t know what you mean. 明鏡 uses this definition: 「その程度が過ぎることを皮肉に言う語」and JMDict uses “utter, extreme”. So you may be onto something regarding “extent”, but no answer suggests how one may even translate this on a surface level (in my opinion).

@whatyouexpect I think "utterly" or "total (nonsense, chaos, ...)" works most of the time.
